# Problems With Saving MySQL Query With Batch File

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, text

I initially labeled this something different but then figured out my problem, but a different problem came up so now I'm editing this some.

First off let me start. I'm not a "coder" and everything I'm doing is all from research. What I'm trying to accomplish is running a batch file on a loop. It connects to MySQL on my VPS just fine. It will then save the return of the MySQL command to text file when information is there. The problem is when there isn't new information in the database, it just saves it as a blank text file. I would rather have it not save to text at all if there's no information on the DB. This is what I have so far. I'm also running this on Windows Server 2008.

```
@echo off
:loop
  timeout /T 5
  mysql --host=111.11.111.11 --port=3306 --user=user_name --password=password --database=db_name --execute="SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1" > results.txt
  if exist c:\users\administrator\desktop\results.txt goto end
  goto loop
  :END
  start program.exe
  exit
```

So what I need is something that saves to text if the MySQL command returns information, but if the MySQL command returns empty it continually does the loop until something is there.

Comment: You're writing code, so you're a coder now! When you say "it didn't work," what happened? Can you provide some logging?

Comment: Ok. I had to change the description of the problem as I fixed the first one just didn't want to start a new post. I'm trying to figure out how I can make the batch ignore the save to text command if the MySQL table returns empty. So any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So does new information = the query turns up something?

Comment: Yes, the DB is designed to delete the line of information once it's used. Which means that it will be blank/null most of the time. So I only want to save a text file if there is that line of information in the DB when the MySQL Query is ran.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way you can parse the results of that query?

Comment: Of course. I can pull information from an individual cell. I can even add another column to the DB that can state a particular word if that helps with the text file trigger. Just don't know how I would incorporate it into the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save the result to a variable and do a check?

```
@echo off
:loop
timeout /T 5
Myans = mysql --host=111.11.111.11 --port=3306 --user=user_name --password=password --database=db_name --    execute="SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 1"
if not %Myans%=="" ( Myans >> results.txt )
if exist c:\users\administrator\desktop\results.txt goto end
goto loop
:END
start program.exe
exit
```